# solr add array convert object keys to array

Tags: node.js, solr

I am adding below array to solr document

```
[
    {
        id: '8ad06c1237d7ac29af2bc0071d55f80d',
        first_name: 'paresh',
        last_name: 'gami'
    }
]
```

Record added successfully in solr but solr convert keys to an array-like below one

```
[
    {
        id: '8ad06c1237d7ac29af2bc0071d55f80d',
        first_name: ['paresh'],
        last_name: ['gami']
    }
]
```

solr add snippet is

```
  solrClient.add(finalSet, function (err) {
     if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
     }
     solrClient.commit();
  });
```

Is the adding setting to make this behavior to as I expected.

I am doing this sample in node.js with https://www.npmjs.com/package/solr-client

Thanks.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your field is either explicitly defined as `multiValued="true"` or you're using the schemaless mode - where all fields will be multivalued by default. Define the field as `multiValued="false"` and you won't get an array back.

Comment: It works when I define a field in a managed-schema.xml file is there any way it works automatically from programing side?

Comment: No, the field has to be defined as single valued to be a single valued field. You should always define the schema explicitly when it comes to any production code anyway.

Comment: Any small exaple snippet you can share?

Comment: For what? You'll need to be more specific - it seems you've already managed to edit your schema :)